# Mistake involving Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: notation, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I ran into a snag in attempting to solve the following problem.

$$x\equiv r\pmod p$$
$$x\equiv0\pmod q$$

I did the following

$$x=k_1q=k_2p+r$$
$$k_1q\equiv r\pmod p$$
$$k_1\equiv rq^{-1}\pmod p$$
$$x=k_1q=(k_3p+rq^{-1})q=$$
$$k_3pq+rq^{-1}q$$
$$x\equiv rq^{-1}q\pmod{pq}$$

I guess the problem occurs in the last $3$ lines.  $q^{-1}$ makes sense when working $\pmod p$, but is there some notation to indicate the inverse is mod $p$ outside of the relavant equivalence?  Secondly, is there any way to simplify that term or is that how it has to remain?

Comment: Just say "let $q'$ be such that $qq' \equiv 1 \mod p$" or equivalent, and work with $q'$ instead of $q^{-1}$. As you say, the latter is very confusing notation.